# How to uninstall Windows 8.1 bundled updates?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, uninstall, windows-8.1-upgrade

I Upgraded Windows 8.1 to a recent version using a retail DVD.

I need to uninstall an update that came with this new version, however there is no option to uninstall it.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Windows was already 8.1, the DVD upgrade is an updated version. The update I'm trying to remove is KB3000850.

Comment: Do other updates provide the Uninstall button as expected? Are you logged in with an Admin account?  Out of curiosity, why is it you want to remove it anyway? What's the actual problem you're running into?

Comment: @Gabriel - You can only remove updates where the information to remove them still exist.  So if you install a installation with the update rolled into it that information doesn't exist.  Please be more helpful with your tagging style.  You tagging this question as `Windows 8` was confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. The DVD was optimized with the command

```
Dism.exe /Image:C:\Mount /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase
```

and [/ResetBase removes the older files, so that you can't uninstall the updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn251565.aspx).

> **Warning** All existing service packs and updates cannot be uninstalled after this command is completed. This will not block the
>   uninstallation of future service packs or updates.