# Can you downgrade Windows 8.1 to an older 8.1 version?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10-preview, windows-8.1-upgrade, downgrade

I recently upgraded an old Windows 8.1 version to a newer December 2014 DVD using the Upgrade Setup assistant, some bundled updates in this version introduced errors.

I'm unable to remove these updates [since they are part of the system](https://superuser.com/questions/873700/how-to-uninstall-windows-8-1-bundled-updates/873877#873877).

Is it possible to use an older 8.1 RTM DVD and Upgrade (actually downgrade) using the Setup wizard?

Another alternative would be upgrading to Windows 10 Technical Preview, which is obviously a risk.

Comment: No; This isn't possible;  The problem you face is that the first rollup `Update 1` actually changed the build of Windows.  Where as the build number I don't believe changed second rollup ( Update 2 )

Comment: why do you want to get rid of the November Update? Which issue do you have?

Comment: Windows Store Apps and PC Settings are not working anymore, [more details on that here](http://superuser.com/posts/comments/1163660?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, It cannot be done. Instead I upgraded to Windows 10 Technical preview, luckily it fixed previous update errors while keeping most programs and settings intact.